# Evaluating $\int\frac{x^4}{x-1} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This question involves long division.

I calculated the value. However, I want to ask two concept questions:

1) Why am I doing long division rather than writing out the form of the partial fraction decomposition of the function.

2) When utilizing long division do I place a constant at the end and if not why?

Here is my set up $\dfrac{x^4+0x^3+0x^2+0x+1}{x-1}$

Comment: Partial fractions only works on a proper fraction, i.e., one where the degree of the polynomial in the numerator is strictly smaller than the degree of the denominator. So, the first step to utilizing partial fractions here is precisely long division.

Comment: $$\frac{x^4}{x-1} = \frac{x^4-1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-1} = x^3+x^2+x+1+\frac{1}{x-1}.$$ It is not difficult to guess what a primitive is.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio My teacher would want me to use long division if it was warranted.

Comment: Ignore him and provide a brief solution. What's wrong in that?

Comment: She gives the grades; thus, I cannot ignore her. Nonetheless, so the constant at the end is unnecssary? i.e., $x^4+0x^3+0x^2+1$

Comment: Partial fractions are not relevant here. The denominator is not factorable.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio basically you anyway just do a division too. You just skip the details.

Comment: @quid: yes, sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial fractions will only work if the degree of the numerator is strictly less than the degree of the denominator. Hence why you need to do long division. You should not add the +1 at the end on the numerator. This changes the value of the fraction.

If you remember differences of squares you can do the division without long division as:

$$\frac{x^4}{x-1}=\frac{x^4-1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-1}$$
$$=\frac{(x^2-1)(x^2+1)}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-1}$$
$$=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-1}$$
$$=(x+1)(x^2+1)+\frac{1}{x-1}$$

Alternatively you could substitution to make the division easier. Let $y=x-1$, hence $dy=dx$ and the integral becomes:

$$\int{\frac{(y+1)^2}{y}dy}=\int\frac{y^4+4y^3+6y^2+4y+1}{y}dy$$
$$=\int y^3+4y^2+6y+4+\frac{1}{y}dy$$

Comment: You said partial fractions will only work if the degree of the numerator is strictly less than the degree of the denominator. Thus, you have to do long division if the numerator and denominator degrees are equal?

Comment: Yes. Your division will in the case yield a constant and a fraction with numerator smaller than denominator.

Answer (score 4):

In integrating a rational function, long division or something accomplishing the same purpose is the first step.  When you divide the numerator $x^4$ by $x-1$ you get a quotient of $x^3+x^2+x+1$ and a remainder of $1$; therefore
$$
\frac{x^4}{x-1} = x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 + \frac 1 {x-1}.
$$

This is just like what you do in arithmetic with integers. For example, when you divide $215$ by $19$ you get a quotient of $11$ and a remainder of $6$; therefore
$$
\frac{215}{19} = 11 + \frac 6 {19}.
$$

Where partial fractions enter is as follows:
$$
\frac{x^4}{x-1} = x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 + \underbrace{\qquad\frac 1 {x-1}\qquad}_{\begin{smallmatrix}
\text{Use partial fractions} \\ \text{for this part if necessary.}
\end{smallmatrix}}
$$

If the denominator is a first-degree polynomial, then partial fractions will not be needed.  If it is a higher-degree polynomial, then the first question is how to factor it.  If it is an irreducible second-degree polynomial, you'll complete the square and end up with an arctangent. If it is a reducible second-degree polynomial, then you go straight to the simplest case of partial fractions.  A higher-than-second-degree polynomial can always be factored into first- and second-degree factors.